# Progressive web app - Obtener el numero de telefono del dispositivo

Tags: typescript, ionic, pwa

Estoy desarrollando una web app en Ionic 4, la cual es accesible desde un browser ya sea en una pc o en un dispositivo movil. En el caso de que la aplicacion se abra en el browser de un dispositivo movil, necesito recuperar el numero de telefono de ese dispositivo.
Hay alguna forma de lograrlo? 
Probe con el plugin Sim de cordova pero solo es compatible con plataformas Mobile

Comment: ¿Dónde está tu código? Edita tu pregunta

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!